# Java inheritance - subclass method override

Tags: java

I am struggling with an inheritance task in Java

I was given an Animal.java class. My homework is to create a subclass called Lion.java. One of the tasks I'm struggling with within the entire task is outputting the type of Lion it is based on the weight of the lion. This is the code for the Animal.java

```
public class Animal {
    private int numTeeth = 0;
    private boolean spots = false;
    private int weight = 0;

    public Animal(int numTeeth, boolean spots, int weight){
        this.setNumTeeth(numTeeth);
        this.setSpots(spots);
        this.setWeight(weight);
    }

    public int getNumTeeth(){
        return numTeeth;
    }

    public void setNumTeeth(int numTeeth) {
        this.numTeeth = numTeeth;
    }

    public boolean getSpots() {
        return spots;
    }

    public void setSpots(boolean spots) {
        this.spots = spots;
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(int weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Lion lion = new Lion(30, false, 80);
        System.out.println(lion);
    }


}
```

This is my code for the Lion.java class so far:

```
public class Lion extends Animal {
    String type = "";

    public Lion(int numTeeth, boolean spots, int weight) {
        super(numTeeth, spots, weight);
    }
    public String type(int weight){
        super.setWeight(weight);
        if(weight <= 80){
            type = "Cub"; 
        }
        else if(weight <= 120){
            type = "Female";
        }
        else{
            type = "Male";
        }
        return type;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() { 
        String output = "Number of Teeth: " + getNumTeeth(); 
        output += "\nDoes it have spots?: " + getSpots();
        output += "\nHow much does it weigh: " + getWeight();
        output += "\nType of Lion: " + type;
        return output;
```

The problem is the output does not return the type based on the if statement above. It's probably a very simple solution but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: _The problem is the output does not return the type based on the if statement above_ Why should it?

Comment: Check with your instructor.  Are you sure you are supposed to add a new method `type()`?  Or are you supposed to override `setWeight()`?  (In other words, we can't tell what's wrong.  You're either calling the methods incorrectly (in other code you haven't shown) or you didn't understand and follow the assignment.  Could be either one.)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis one of the questions in the task is "Add a method in this class which sets the lion type based on it’s weight (note that the
weight is a derived field from the superclass)."

Comment: "Add a method" doesn't mean add a method and do nothing else.  I think you were also supposed to do something else.  (I'm not saying what I think it is because I think figuring it out is the whole point of the assignment.)

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. Why do you think your `toString()` method in any way involves the `type` method, and its logic?

Comment: You should probably remove the parameter from the type method, since you were told that the type should be based on the derived `weight` field, not on a parameter.  Also, it's not the best idea to have a field and a method with the same name - it can get confusing, especially while you're learning the fundamentals.  So I recommend replacing `public String type(int weight){` with `public String evaluateType() {` or something similar.

Comment: Well, since we've basically given away the answer now, I also will add that `evaluateType(()` could be private and only called from an overridden `setWeight()` method.  That would probably be the cleanest way of doing it.  But OP make sure to tell your instructor you got help, by now it will be pretty obvious that someone wrote most of this code for you.

Answer (score 0):

In toString method, instead of type replace with type() method.

```
@Override
public String toString() { 
      String output = "Number of Teeth: " + getNumTeeth(); 
      output += "\nDoes it have spots?: " + getSpots();
      output += "\nHow much does it weigh: " + getWeight();
      output += "\nType of Lion: " + type(getWeight());
      return output;
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a good look at your `Lion` constructor

```
public Lion(int numTeeth, boolean spots, int weight) {
    super(numTeeth, spots, weight);
}
```

This doesn't do anything for the type (your public `type` method).

In order to set the private `type` class variable you need to either call the `type` method in the constructor or after the object has been created but before you call the `toString` method. For example

```
public Lion(int numTeeth, boolean spots, int weight) {
    super(numTeeth, spots, weight);
    type(weight);
}
```

Note that, as pointed out in the comments, you probably would be better off handling the `type` directly in the `setWeight` method. You can do something like

```
@Override
public void setWeight(int weight) {
    super.setWeight(weight);
    type(weight);
}
```

and leave the constructor alone.

Taking it one step further, you could refactor your code such that the `type` method has no parameter (you've already set the `weight` member).

Comment: This will "work" but I don't think it completes the assignment.  I think it's more likely the OP was supposed to override `setWeight()`.  Just a guess though.

Comment: @markspace Yes, thanks for pointing that out. I've modified the answer.